# can I repeat the word if it has a different meaning?

Tags: word-usage, repetition

> Radio programs are very useful in an emergency. You should have **a radio** at home.

> Radio programs are very useful in an emergency. You should have **one** at home.

Should I repeat the word "radio" here or should I avoid the repetition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should repeat.

Otherwise it means, "You should have a radio program at home".

The rule is that you should not repeat the same noun phrase. There's no rule against repeating the same word. "Radio program" is not the same noun phrase as "radio", so there's no issue here.

Comment: Or you could say "You should have a set at home" (an individual radio or TV receiver can be called a 'set').

Comment: Agreed.  Yes, the word *radio* appears in both sentences, but in the first sentence, it's only modifying the word *program*, which is the real noun of the sentence.